# Using array of pointers to object in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to save objects as pointers in dynamic array but i have problem.
This is my code, there are three classes and i need to have array (arrayoftwo) of poiters to class Two that would work further with class Three and so on. I have two problems. One is that i cant figure out how to dynamically allocate space for my arrayoftwo (which i need to dynamically resize by number of stored pointers) and second problem is how to exactly store pointers to objects without destroying object itself.
Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class One {
public:
    bool addTwo(int a);

private:
    void getspace(void);
    class Two {
    public:
        int a;
    private:

        class Three {
            /*...*/
        };
        Three arrayofThree[];

    };
    int freeindex;
    int allocated;
    Two *arrayoftwo[];
};

void One::getspace(void){
    // how to allocate space for array of pointers ?
    arrayoftwo=new *Two[100];
    allocated=100;
}
bool One::addTwo(int a){
    Two temp;
    temp.a=a;
    getspace();
    arrayoftwo[freeindex]=&temp;
    freeindex++;
    return true;
    //after leaving this method, will the object temp still exist or pointer stored in array would be pointing on nothing ?
}

int main() {
    bool status;
    One x;
    status = x . addTwo(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** I cant use vector or any other advanced containers

Comment: Why not using an std::vector?

Comment: for my future work on this, it has to be array, i cant use vector or other STL

Comment: Can you explain /why/? Surely if you want to do future work, you want to do do good work? You can always go back to C if you really need to (one benefit is that the `arrayoftwo[]` might actually compile, I'm not sure)

Comment: Try isolating a specific thing that you're stuck with. Your code contains a multitude of unclarities that may or may not be relevant. What exactly is the **first** thing that you are stuck at?

Comment: `vector` is just a wrapper for doing `new[]` that copies and deletes it for you at the right time, there's no reason at all not to use it. It will save you a lot of development time. For example, as written your `One` and `Two` classes violate the Rule of Three so you could easily run into memory errors without even realizing what is going on. Also, none of this is exception-safe.

Comment: @UpAndAdam `Two *arrayoftwo[];` in a struct is not legal in C++. See `[class.mem]#10` "Non-static data members shall not have incomplete types"

Comment: oh missed the `*` touche, comment removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` will not exist after leaving `addTwo`; the pointer you store to it is invalid at that point. Instead of storing the object as a local variable, allocate it on the heap with new:

```
  Two* temp = new Two();
```

To allocate an array of pointers:

```
  Two** arrayoftwo;  // declare it like this
  // ...
  arrayoftwo = new Two*[100];
```

And `getspace` should either be passed `a` (from `addTwo`) or `a` should be stored as the member variable `allocated` and `getspace` should access it from there. Otherwise it's assuming `100`.